# How to create a Spark Dataframe(v1.6) on a secured Hbase Table?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, hbase

I am trying to create a spark dataframe on a existing HBase Table(HBase is secured via Kerberos). I need to perform some spark Sql operations on this table.

I have tried creating a RDD on a Hbase table but unable to convert it into dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create hive external table with HBase storage handler and then use that table to run your spark-sql queries.

**Creating the hive external table:**

```
CREATE TABLE foo(rowkey STRING, a STRING, b STRING)
STORED BY ‘org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler’
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (‘hbase.columns.mapping’ = ‘:key,f:c1,f:c2’)
TBLPROPERTIES (‘hbase.table.name’ = ‘bar’);
```

**Spark-sql:**
    val df=spark.sql("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE …")

Note: Here spark is a SparkSession

Comment: Table in Hbase has close to ~10cr records. Will it be ideal to create hive table , considering large amount of data?

Comment: This will work like a view. It wont be importing the data from Hbase to Hive. It will just give you the flexibility of running normal sql queries over HBase table. Even I've done the same thing with my HBase table having millions of record. Hope this will help

Comment: Hi @abhishekchaurasiya, Abhishek Jangid i have same requirement would like to know your experience on this. I have a hbase table which has around ten million records. I wrote python and java code for converting hbase table to dataframe.

Comment: Hey @JaiPrakash,  what kind of help do you need ?

Comment: Hi Abhishek, Any of kind of stats if you can provide like your hbase table size and how much time it takes for any typical query. rough estimates wil lhelp me.